# How can I achieve the mouseover effect like on wikipedia?

Tags: css

I want to achieve the css effect like wikipedia. If I mouseover on any reference number like [1], the bottom reference content will be signled out with a css border effect. How can I achieve that? By mouseovering on one link but other element respond... Just could not figure out how to do that.

I hope I have made my point clear.

Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Harbin_smog#cite_note-14

My testing code:

```
<!-- declare that this document is written in HTML 5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>      

        <style>
            p:target {background:lightblue;}
        </style>

    </head>

        <!-- Beginning of the <body> tag -->

    <body>

        <p><a id='faq1link' href="#faq1content">Jump to FAQ FAQ 1</a></p>
        <p><a id='faq2link' href="#faq2content">Jump to FAQ FAQ 2</a></p>
        <p><a id='faq3link' href="#faq3content">Jump to FAQ FAQ 2</a></p>

        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

        <p id="faq1content"><b>FAQ content 1...</b></p>
        <p id="faq2content"><b>FAQ content 2...</b></p>
        <p id="faq3content"><b>FAQ content 3...</b></p>     


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What special in wikipedia??? Its just `text-decoration:underline`

Comment: Hover effects varies on Wikipedia according to user preferences... I have a Javascript file which give more information when I hover on a Wikipedia link. Please give a screenshot.

Comment: *Note: prefer using `margin` than multiples `<br>`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS only allow elements to react on parent's hover (maybe siblings too, I'm not sure, if someone can tell).

You'll have to use Javascript for this.

For convenience, here's an example using jQuery:

### HTML

```
<span data-tooltip-id="ref0">Reference 0</span>
...
<div id="ref0">This is the reference 0</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.elements-to-hover').hover(function(){
    var idRef = $(this).data('tooltip-id');
    $('#'+idRef).addClass('yourBorderedClass');

},function(){
    var idRef = $(this).data('tooltip-id');
    $('#'+idRef).removeClass('yourBorderedClass');

});
```

The first function is triggered on `mouseenter`, the second function on `mouseleave`.

See [jQuery's `.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) for reference.

### Edit

On your case, you'll bind this function to all your reference anchors:

```
$('#faq1link, #faq2link, #faq3link').hover(function(event){
    var idRef = $(this).attr('href'); // or this.href
    $('#'+idRef).addClass('yourBorderedClass');

},function(){
    var idRef = $(this).attr('href'); // or this.href
    $('#'+idRef).removeClass('yourBorderedClass');

});
```

**I strongly suggest you** to add either a common `class` to your `<a>`, or add a identifiable wrapper for these elements. It will allow you to bind `hover()` without specifying each `<a>` tag, using something like `$('.refAnchors')` or `$('.refAnchorsWrapper a')`.

Comment: Thanks Bigood, But like wikipedia, there are lots of reference, does that mean I have to write the code you provided for each reference item? Are there any smarter way to do that?

Comment: HTML5. Use `data-` tags and javascript. Jquery would be quick and dirty

Comment: Thanks! @Bigood, that's it! You have expand my mind on how to solve this! Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't achievable by pure CSS as tooltips are an OS-dependant feature.

However it can be done with JS - try out [qTip](http://qtip2.com/) or make your own tooltip jQuery script.

A relatively simple way to override all tooltips would be:

```
$('[title]')
.each(function() {
    $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
})
.hover(function(e) {
    window.tooltipID = 't' + (Math.random() + '').replace('0.', '');
    $('<div />', {
        id: tooltipID,
        class: 'tooltip-content',
        html: $(this).data('title'),
        style: 'position: absolute;
        top: ' + e.pageY + '; left: ' + e.pageX
    }).appendTo('body');
}, function() {
    $('#' + window.tooltipID).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with CSS but is possible with jQuery.

You can use qTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with javascript and without any framework :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <style type="text/css">
            *[data-hoverWithLink=true] {
                background: lightblue;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                Array.map.call(null, document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(link) {
                    var href = link.getAttribute("href");
                    if(href.substring(0, 1)) {
                        var target = document.getElementById(href.substring(1));
                        link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                            target.setAttribute("data-hoverWithLink", true);
                        });
                        link.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
                            target.setAttribute("data-hoverWithLink", false);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="#faq1content">Jump to FAQ FAQ 1</a></p>
        <p><a href="#faq2content">Jump to FAQ FAQ 2</a></p>
        <p><a href="#faq3content">Jump to FAQ FAQ 2</a></p>

        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

        <p id="faq1content"><b>FAQ content 1...</b></p>
        <p id="faq2content"><b>FAQ content 2...</b></p>
        <p id="faq3content"><b>FAQ content 3...</b></p>     
    </body>
</html>
```